# Heroku + Unable to verify SSL Certificate for api.heroku.com

Tags: ssl, heroku

While accessing pushing the code to Heroku from my system, I am getting this error. I tried a lot but unable to remove it.

```
WARNING: Unable to verify SSL certificate for api.heroku.com
To disable SSL verification, run with HEROKU_SSL_VERIFY=disable
```

Suggest something !!

Comment: What happens if you pull up https://api.heroku.com in your browser?  Do you get the same message?

Comment: How it is possible to pull api.heroku.com

Comment: Just in your web browser.  Enter https://api.heroku.com  - Or click the link here.

Comment: As I follow you say, reached to my Heroku account. Now ?

Comment: And you didn't get an SSL warning message?

Comment: NO, I dnt get any SSL warning message..

Comment: So you are only getting the warning through Ruby.  Maybe Ruby doesn't have all of required SSL support.  Not sure how to fix that.  Maybe uninstall and then install the latest.

Comment: I have done twice but no result in hands.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a version problem. 
Try uninstalling heroku gem with 'gem uninstall heroku' deleting de executable also.
After this try 'gem install heroku -v "<2.0.0"'
After this try to write the command 'heroku keys:add' and enter your email and password
For me this worked fine.